# How to open a modal component from inside of another modal component without having a circular dependency?

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I have two ngx-bootstrap modals created as a standalone components (not with template variables) - Login modal and Register modal. Each of the modals are have separate components which are located in my shared module and can be called from other modules. But the thing is that there is an option these modals to call each other - you can click a button from the login modal which has to bring you the Register modal and vice versa. When I try doing this using the BsModalService I get circular dependency errors since I have imported the login component in the register component and the register component in the login component.

I've tried to put this modal switching logic in a service with the hope that I won't get a circular dependency but it didn't help.

```js
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
   import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
   import { UserService } from 'src/app/core/services';
   import { User } from 'src/app/core';
   import { RegisterModalComponent } from '../register-modal/register-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-modal',
  templateUrl: './login-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-modal.component.css']
})
export class LoginModalComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      // form definition
  });

  constructor(
    public loginModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private user: UserService,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
     // form submit code ...
    // hide the current modal
    this.loginModalRef.hide();
  }

  openRegisterModal() {
    // hide the current modal
    this.loginModalRef.hide();
    // open the new modal
    this.modalService.show(RegisterModalComponent, {
      animated: true,
      class: 'modal-lg'
    });
  }
}
```

I have included only the code from the login modal since the situation on the other side is similar.

Comment: same issue , do you have a better solution ?

Comment: @AidosOmurzakov It's been a long time since I worked on this project, so I don't have an update. I already left a comment that I decided to use one single component for the modal and use ngSwitch to switdh between different components. Of course this is not a good solution but it worked for me at the time. And another thing that makes me think was the issue - I used to import the core module of the app in other modules (including the module with the modals). As I later learned - this is wrong and the core module should be imported only once in the main app module. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that as a temporary solution I just made one modal component to serve the purpose as modal and I refactored the login and the register components to be like a regular components so I can include them inside the modal and switch them with ngIf depending on the parameters that I'm calling the modal with.